# What might cause extreme internet slowness in Windows 11 Home?

Tags: networking, router, performance, windows-11

I have a desktop computer with:

- **Mainboard**: Asus Prime Z690-P
- **CPU**: Intel Core I7 12700F
- **Internet Router**: Dual Band AC D256DG
- A genuine copy of Windows 11 Home.

I have an internet connection of 40 MB/s download.

### My problem

Though the connection is steady, it is *extremely* slow at about, I'd guess, less than 1 MBP/s. Even trying to test the internet speed sopmetimes won't start (test websites *slowly* load but the tests don't even start. However, some **do** start very slowly and show 40 MB/s).

The problem happens both with a cable **and** with WiFi

### Things I've tried but that didn't help

- Updating Windows 11 (with computer resets and double checks)
- Turning on/off and also **resetting** my internet router
- Taking down all 3 Windows firewalls:

  - Domain network
  - Private network
  - Public network

### My question

What might cause extreme internet slowness in Windows 11 Home?

Comment: What version of WiFi is the device is using.  It's easy enough to guess that the D256DG is using WiFi 5.  Please [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: According to the question, some speed-test sites **do** load and then *show the expected speed, 40 MB/s.* So the question should be,*why do those sites load so slowly*? The cause might be your ISP -- how do other PC's behave when testing throughput? Also, see if the OS is the bottleneck -- try running another OS from USB, e.g., Live Ubuntu, which has a web browser, and test the speed with that.

Comment: You need to specify the environment where you experience "internet slowness", such as what's going on in your local network, which internet server you're connected to, etc. Obviously, sometimes there's nothing whatever "slow" about your connection if you're getting 40MB/s. Data transfer rates can vary by several orders of magnitude, depending on what you're connected to.

Answer (score -2):

Most likely programs you are running, but since you are not showing an application list it is difficult to say for sure.

Here is link that might help.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/why-is-my-internet-connection-so-slow-c68cf021-c5cf-db6f-eade-7c9d8bd78aa1

Look up the section *Computer woes: spyware, viruses, and other programs*

Only use 5ghz in the same room as well, 2.4 from other rooms.
Test it with a wired connection.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).